# Limit of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}$ with Riemann sum

Tags: integration

Determine if $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N^*}}$ such that $u_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}$ converge and find its limit.

Below my answer :

$$u_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\;\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}$$

Let

$ \begin{array}l f :&[0,1]&\to &\mathbb{R}\\ &x&\to &\dfrac{1}{1+x^2} \end{array}$

And a tagged partition $P(\sigma_n,\zeta_n)$ such that :

$\sigma_n =\left\{\dfrac{k}{n},k\in[\![ 0,n]\!]\right\}$ and $\zeta_n=\left\{\dfrac{k}{n},k\in[\![ 0,n-1]\!]\right\}$

$$\\S_P\;\;=\;\;\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\;\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}\;\;=\;\;\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\; f\left(\zeta_n\right)\;\;\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}\;\; \int_0^1f(x)dx$$
because $f$ is continuous $\implies f$ is R-integrable

$$\boxed{u_n= S_P+ \dfrac{1}{2n}\;\;\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}\;\; \int_0^1f(x)dx=\dfrac{\pi}{4}}$$

My question is, the correction doesn't take account of the term $\dfrac{1}{2n}$, but the sum has got $n+1$ terms and not $n$ terms. I know that $\dfrac{1}{2n}\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$, but is it correct to say straight away : $$u_n=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\;\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}\;\; \int_0^1f(x)dx$$

Comment: No, it is not a Riemann sum.

Comment: thanks, but may you be more explicit, please?

Comment: After you have rearranged as you did you have a Riemann sum of a continuous function, so you have it correctly.

Comment: @Stu $u_n $ is not a Riemann sum but $S_p $ is.

Comment: understood, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write the sum as 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+(\tfrac{k}{n})^2}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+(\tfrac{k}{n})^2}\right)+\frac{1}{2n}
$$
then by additivity of limits, you will get 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+(\tfrac{k}{n})^2}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+(\tfrac{k}{n})^2}\right)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2n}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+(\tfrac{k}{n})^2}
\end{align*}
so yes, it turns out that this is essentially just the Riemann sum as you said.

Comment: Please be more specific @Salahamam_Fatima

Comment: @ThomasGrubb: $1/2n$.